# MapReduce works in Mongo Shell, not in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to run a MapReduce query in my application. I've created the relevant JS, and verified it to work via Mongo-Shell:

```
var map = function() {
    if (this.class_artist != null)
    for (var i = 0; i < this.class_artist.length; i++) {
        var key = {
            artist: this.class_artist[i],
            language:  this.language.substring(0,2),
        };
        var value = {
            count: 1
        };
        emit(key, value);
    }
}
var reduce = function(key, value) {
    var sum = 0;
    value.forEach(function(value) {
        sum += value['count'];
    });
    return {count: sum};
}
db.articles.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: {inline: 1}})
```

I've got the following c# translation:

```
    var articleCollection = database.GetCollection<Article_Base>("articles");

string map = @"var map = function() {
            if (this.class_artist != null)
            for (var i = 0; i < this.class_artist.length; i++) {
                var key = {
                    artist: this.class_artist[i],
                    language:  this.language.substring(0,2),
                };
                var value = {
                    count: 1
                };
                emit(key, value);
            }
        }";
string reduce = @"var reduce = function(key, value) {
            var sum = 0;
            value.forEach(function(value) {
                sum += value['count'];
            });
            return {count: sum};
        }";
var options = new MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
options.SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Inline);
var result = articleCollection.MapReduce(map, reduce, options).GetResults();
```

However, even though I'm using the same map & reduce functions, the c# code returns no results.

I'm new to mapReduce, and despite reading the documentation I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try dropping the "var" declarations and just define the functions as strings.

Comment: That works! If you change your response from Comment to Reply, I will accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation is too literal, you only need to define the function as a string:

```
string map = @"function() {" // and the rest of it
```

Then the mapReduce method has something to process